# CSS table class is affecting all tables outside of class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a new page up containing a responsive table, using the code below. I've put the code in its own class 'resptable' but for some reason its affecting all tables (even ones not in any class) throughout my site. I can't seem to find why. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

The CSS -

```
    /* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
.resptable table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
.resptable tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
.resptable th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
.resptable td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}


/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    .resptable table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    .resptable thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    .resptable tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    .resptable td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    .resptable td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
    .resptable td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<table class="resptable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Matman</td>
        <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The</td>
        <td>Tick</td>
        <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Such selector:

   ```
   .resptable table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr
   ```

   points to:

   ```
   .resptable table,
   thead,
   tbody,
   th,
   td,
   tr
   ```

   So, just first selector in a list has your class `resptable`. Others are points to every `thead`, `tbody`, `th`, `td`, `tr` elements (without your class `resptable`).
2. And other point is that you `table` has `resptable` class. So, `table` is not in `.resptable` but `table` is `.resptable`:

   ```
   table.resptable
   ```

> I believe you was trying to write another one:
>
> ```
> table.resptable,
> .resptable thead,
> .resptable tbody,
> .resptable th,
> .resptable td,
> .resptable tr
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I see how that would work, however it now causes the tableto vanish altogether when the window is reduced (on mobiles etc) I just created this to show you -
[link]https://jsfiddle.net/uab01ab6/

Comment: Here is the original working code (before I added the class that stops it working) [link] https://jsfiddle.net/anbwmedy/

Comment: You have text defined by CSS `content` properties inside a media query. When screen get smaller width your rules are not applied. May be you'd better not to use `content` for that.

Comment: In what part original working code do not fit your goals?

Comment: The original code affects ALL tables throughout my site, therefore I am trying to put original code in its own class ' .resptable' as I don't want whole site affected

Comment: I took original code and add `resptable` class to it. It works: https://jsfiddle.net/anbwmedy/1/

Comment: Thank Vladimir, by looking at your code I can see what I did wrong. Much Appreciated